# Shared_preload_libraries in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, libraries

Shared Library Preloading -

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements' # (change requires restart)
```

After changing this I restart the server also but no change reflected in the system.

Also, create an extension.

> ERROR-SQL Error [55000]: ERROR: pg_stat_statements must be loaded via shared_preload_libraries

Comment: select * from pg_settings where name = 'shared_preload_libraries'
There is column pending_restart show true.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was overridden by the other config file named "60_extensions.conf" from "/var/lib/pgsql/14/data/conf.d" directory. I got it from the "sourcefile" column from this query "select * from
pg_settings where name = 'shared_preload_libraries' "